# How does angular pass the mat-select value of the parent component to the child component？

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
parent.html
 <p>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="country">
    <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
    <mat-select panelClass="select" disableRipple required
                (keyup)="newCountry(value)" [(ngModel)]="value">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let c of countries"
                  [value]="c.value">{{c.key}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>

parent.ts
  countries = countries;

  value: string = '';

  @Output() country: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  newCountry(value: string) {
    this.country.emit(value);
  }

child.html
 <phone (country)="country($event)" (number)="number($event)"></phone>

child.ts
country(value: string) {
    this.signup.country = value;
  }
```

Why can't I get the mat-select value of the parent component? How to send the mat-select value of the parent component to the child component?

Comment: the code you have shared does not show where in the parent component you  are calling the child.  parent/child relationship implies that somewhere in the parent.html there would be <child-selector></child-selector> tag. I would recomend reviewing the official documentation on this topic. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Solved, `(mouseenter)="newCountry(value)"`,just bind the mouse event,Thanks